# Decode doesn't decode correctly

Tags: java, utf-8, base64, decode, encode

I'm having problems decoding a byte[] to string following a tutorial...
This is my code:

```
import java.util.Base64;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Main
{
    private static final Charset UTF_8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "hello";
        System.out.println("Original text: " + text);
        byte[] aesByte = text.getBytes(UTF_8);
        System.out.println("Original text in byte[]: " + aesByte);
        String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(aesByte);
        System.out.println("Encode original text from byte[] to String: " + encoded);
        byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded);
        System.out.println("Decode string to byte[] of original text: " + decoded);
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
Original text: hello
Original text in byte[]: [B@2a139a55
Encode original text from byte[] to String: aGVsbG8=
Decode string to byte[] of original text: [B@15db9742
```

Isn't suppose to work?

Comment: You're printing a byte array, not a string.

Comment: Yeah it seems like I printing the location of memory from the primitive array of java (byte[]) and not the content of it... How could I access the content?

Comment: You do the opposite of `text.getBytes(UTF_8);`, that is convert the byte array to string. (see duplicate target below)

Comment: When trying to print Arrays.toString(decoded) the output is a list of integers

Comment: I'm not finding the answer or how to do it...

Comment: It's the first answer in the link I gave you `String str = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`